# google cloud create Http function to list of objects from bucket in python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

```
from google.cloud import storage


def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
```

When I am creating cloud function using http. Its not deploying.

```
# Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the google-cloud-storage in the requirements.txt and check if a function with the same name exists as the entry point. The main file need to have a function with the same name as the entry point

Comment: from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
import time
from random import randint

def test_read(bucketName):
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucketName)
  files = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='')
  fileList = [file.name for file in files ]
  myList = [i.split('/')[-1] for i in fileList] 
    print(myList)

read_from_storage(bucketName)

Comment: I have tried different code but its failing in deployment.

Comment: yes. I have mentioned packages in requirement and CF entry point is "list_blobs". Still its failing in deployment.

Comment: Could you let me see your code? I can help you better if you do, @VarshaSahu